# Need help on tree like structure data retrieval

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have an 'superior object' of type HierarchyNode which will have childnodes (each child node may have their child nodes) of it of the sametype HierarchyNode.

I should read the childnodes of reqested parent node from the 'superior object'. So my code goes as follow (caller -- superiorObject.IdentifySubNodeOfRequestedNode(...)). But stopRecursiveCall is false in foreach loop eventhough if loop is executed and also getting not all code return values exception. How to resolve this and return childnodes or is there anyother better solution to this problem? Thanks

```
public List<HierarchyNode> IdentifySubNodeOfRequestedNode(int reqstedId, Boolean stopRecursiveCall)
{
    if (this.UserId == reqstedId)
    {
        stopRecursiveCall = true;
        return this.ChildNodes;
    }

    foreach (HierarchyNode childNode in this.ChildNodes)
    {
         childNode.IdentifySubNodeOfRequestedNode(reqstedId, stopRecursiveCall);
         if (stopRecursiveCall)
             break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything within your method. Does it even compile?

Comment: Also, you are always checking against this.UserId, you're not recursing on its child nodes...

Comment: @digEmAll actually he is. He's calling `childNode.IdentifySubNodeOfRequestedNode()`

Comment: @digEmAll that's because 'this' changes upon recursion

Comment: Sure, I didn't notce that this method was inside HierarchyNode, sorry...

Comment: this.UserId needs to be checked inorder to return its childnodes. So recursive call modify 'this'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no need for the bool

```
public class HierarchyNode
{
    private decimal UserId;
    private List<HierarchyNode> ChildNodes;

    public List<HierarchyNode> IdentifySubNodeOfRequestedNode(int reqstedId)
    {
        if (this.UserId == reqstedId)
        {
            return this.ChildNodes;
        }

        return this.ChildNodes.
            Select(childNode => childNode.IdentifySubNodeOfRequestedNode(reqstedId)).
            FirstOrDefault(children => children != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, my. I haven't tried C# since 2.0, but all those functional idioms do look tasty.

Comment: @ Clueless: Solved my issue. Great! Thanks!!. My complete algorithm is very poor apart from using bool? as Victor Nicollet mentined?? Where i lagged ?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm has several flaws that stem from an underlying major issue : you are trying to separate the main purpose of the algorithm (to find and return something) and an ad hoc optimization (to stop looping once that thing is found).

In pseudocode, what your algorithm should be doing is:

```
find(id):
  if (this.id == id):
    return this.children
  foreach (child in this.children): 
    found = child.find(id)
    if (found != null): 
      return found
  return null
```

This ties together the act of finding a value and the act of stopping recursion (recursion stops when a value is returned).